# Proof of non-convergence of fixed point iteration

Tags: solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose we have a function $f$ which has a fixed point $\alpha$. Moreover, $|f'(\alpha)|>1$.

I aim to prove that the fixed point iteration does not converge locally to $\alpha$ (only sequences eventually constant to $\alpha$ converge). Is the following proof correct and can be perfected?

*Take $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small so that
$$|f'(\alpha)|-\varepsilon>1.$$
Since $f$ is differentiable at $\alpha$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that*

$$|f(x)-\alpha - f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)|\leq\varepsilon |x-\alpha|,$$
*for every $|x-\alpha|<\delta$. Therefore,*
\begin{align*}|f(x)-\alpha|&\geq |f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)|-|f(x)-\alpha-f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)|\\
&\geq (|f'(\alpha)-\varepsilon)|x-\alpha|\\
&>|x-\alpha|,\end{align*}
*whenever $0<|x-\alpha|<\delta$.*

*Now, take a point $x_0\in\left]\alpha-\delta,\alpha+\delta\right[$
and construct the iteration sequence $\{x_n\}:=\{f^n(x_0)\}$. Suppose that $x_n\neq \alpha$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $x_n$ tends to $\alpha$. Thus, there exists some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>n_0$ we have that $|x_n-\alpha|<\delta$. Then,*
$$|x_n-\alpha|=|f(x_{n-1})-\alpha|>|x_{n-1}-\alpha|>\cdots>|x_{n_0}-\alpha|.$$
*Taking limits we deduce that*
$$\lim_n |x_n-\alpha|\geq |x_{n_0}-\alpha|>0.$$
*This is a contradiction.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of your proof is very good. I could nitpick about a few things:

- "Taking limits we deduce that..." - it is nowhere said that $\lim_n |x_n-\alpha|$ exists. (However, all the values $|x_n-\alpha|$ being at least as big as $|x_{n_0}-\alpha|>0$ is enough to conclude that $x_n$ does not converge to $\alpha$.)
- The point $x_0$ may not need to be in $(\alpha-\delta, \alpha+\delta)$, all we need is that, for *some* $n_0$, assuming convergence to $\alpha$, *all* elements of the sequence, starting from $x_{n_0}$, *will* be in $(\alpha-\delta, \alpha+\delta)$.

---

As for the alternative proof, consider the sequence $x_n$ given by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ and assume it converges to $\alpha$ but $x_n\ne \alpha$ for all $n$. Then:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-\alpha}{x_n-\alpha}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(\alpha)}{x_n-\alpha}=f'(\alpha)$$

so, taking moduli (absolute values) and recalling that the limit of the modulus is the modulus of the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_{n+1}-\alpha|}{|x_n-\alpha|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}-\alpha}{x_n-\alpha}\right\rvert=|f'(\alpha)|>1$$

which implies that, for some $n_0$, and all $n\ge n_0$ we also have $\frac{|x_{n+1}-\alpha|}{|x_n-\alpha|}>1$ i.e. $|x_{n+1}-\alpha|>|x_n-\alpha|$ which then implies (as in your proof) that $|x_n-\alpha|>|x_{n_0}-\alpha|>0$ for $n>n_0$, so $x_n$ cannot converge to $\alpha$.