Fixed point iteration and convergence and contraction mapping
Let $p\ge 2$ be an integer, $a>0$ and $f$, $g$ be two functions defined for $x>0$ by $g(x)=ax^{1-p}$, $f(x)=x+\lambda(g(x)-x)$. Let $x_{0}$ be an appropriate initial guess, close enough to the root $a^{\frac{1}{p}}$.
a) Does the sequence $x_{n+1}=g(x_{n})$ converge to the root $a^{\frac{1}{p}}$?
b)For which values of $\lambda$ does the fixed point iteration $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$ converge to $a^{\frac{1}{p}}$?
My attempt was to show that $g(x)=ax^{1-p}$ is contraction mapping therefore I tried the absolute value of the derivative of $g$ to be less than $1$ which is $|(1-p)ax^{-p}|$ but this may not hold for very small $x$ values so I could not do in that way. If someone can help especially about the first part I will be really pleased. In b) I think I should use part a) is this correct?

(a) No. Note that
$$|g' (x)| = |1 - p| |a x^{-p}|$$
When $p > 2$, we have that the first factor $|1 - p| > 1$. At the point $y = a^\frac{1}{p}$, the second factor is precisely equal to $1$, no matter the value of $a$ or $p$. Therefore, since $|g' (y)| > 1$, the iteration never converges to $y$, unless we select $x_0 = y$ or incidentally $x_n = y$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
When $p = 2$, something interesting happens. Your function $g (x) = a x^{-1}$; note that $g^2 (x) = x$. In general, $g^n (x) = a x^{-1}$ for $n$ odd, and $g^n (x) = x$ for $n$ even. This shows that the iteration never converges to $y$ unless $x_0 = \sqrt{a}$ (because if not, the sequence contains infinitely many elements equal to $x_0$).
(b) Following a similar approach, we take the derivative:
$$f' (x) = 1 + \lambda (g' (x) - 1)$$
Substituting,
$$f' (x) = (1 - \lambda) + \lambda a (1 - p) x^{-p}$$
At the point $x = y = a^\frac{1}{p}$, we see that
$$f' (y) = 1 - \lambda p$$
If we choose
$$0 < \lambda < \frac{2}{p}$$
then $|f' (y)| < 1$, and there is some region around $x = y$ for which the fixed point iteration converges to $y$.

Thank you for your effort the issue is fixed point theorem implies only one side. According to it if $|1-p|>1$ we can not directly say this does not converge. I know like that are you using something else?

If $|\frac{dg}{dy}|>1$ we can not say iteration does not converge by directly fixed point theorem

@mathsandchess It's relatively easy to show. See here for one way to prove it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607132/proof-of-non-convergence-of-fixed-point-iteration
